# Javascript for loop through JSON values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object `r`:

```
[ 
  {
    "id"     : "3443",
    "name"   : "Joe",
    "date1"  : "254",
    "date4"  : "261"
  },
  { "id"     : "50942",
    "name"   : "John",
    "date2"  : "192",
    "date4"  : "195"
  },
  { "id"     : "2524",
    "name"   : "Mary",
    "date1"  : "153",
    "date4"  : "163"
  }
]
```

and I wish to have a Javascript For loop to go through the dateX values.
I know that X is between 1 and a Max value.

But following code does not work:

```
for (j=1; j<=Max; j=j+1) {
  datestring = 'date' + j;
  if (isset(r[i].datestring)) value[j] = r[i].datestring;
  else value[j] = null; 
}
```

---

Forgot to explain that I defined the isset function as:

```
function isset(variable) {
  return typeof(variable) != "undefined" && variable !== null;
}
```

Comment: Have you defined `isset` anywhere? `isset` exists as a function in PHP, but not JavaScript.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Consider looping through the existing properties instead of looping through all possible property names (see my answer below).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First iterate through the array of objects with an ordinary for loop. Then iterate through the properties of each object with `for (var p in obj)` and check the value of `p`. Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];

    for (var p in obj) {
        if (/^date\d+$/.test(p)) {
            var value = obj[p];
            // p is a dateX property name and value is the value
        }
    }
}
```

It's counter-intuitive and inefficient to loop through all possible property values to check their existence. Instead, loop through the actual properties and test their names against your pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a property called `datestring` when you should be doing `r[i][datestring]` or `r[i]['date'+j]`. This will read the value of the variable and look a property with that name.

Comment: Just to elaborate `r[i].datestring === r[i]['datestring']` and `r[i][datestring] === r[i]['dateX']` (X being whatever iteration of the loop)

Comment: Using r[i][datestring] I am getting an error "TypeError Object Expected"

Comment: Where is it coming from? I don't know what your `isset` function is doing.

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer:** if you came here looking for an example of looping through JSON values in the same method that the original poster is asking, Ates answer below mine is a much much better method, please do not use this one.

Im not sure why you'd want to do whatever you're trying because you're going to be overwriting values in `value` like crazy but you probably know more about what you're doing than we do so heres a working example based on your code.

```
var r = [
{
"id":"3443",
"name":"Joe",
"date1":"254",
"date4":"261"
},
{
"id":"50942",
"name":"John",
"date2":"192",
"date4":"195"
},
{
"id":"2524",
"name":"Mary",
"date1":"153",
"date4":"163"
}
];


var max = 10; // guess

var value = {};

for(var i in r)
{
    for (j=0; j<=max; j++)
    {
        datestring = 'date'+j;

        if (undefined != r[i][datestring])
        {
            value[j] = r[i][datestring];
        }
        else
        {
            value[j] = null;
        }
    }
}
```